# using fgetcsv from a file on a FTP server

Tags: php, zend-framework, csv

I need to read a list of CSV files from an FTP and delete them after I successfully read them.

Until now, i opened the csv file using `fopen` into a resource and then used `fgetcsv` to read the csv lines from it.

```
  $res = fopen($url);
  while ($csv_row = fgetcsv($res, null, self::DELIMITER)) {
  .....
  }
```

The problem is that I need to read a list of csv files and delete them too. the ftp_get function save the file into a local file. I rather avoid that. any way I can keep using the `fgetcsv` function with the `ftp_nlist` & `ftp_connect` functions? ?

Comment: What issues have you encountered when trying to use `fgetcsv`?

Comment: fgetcsv can't read from a ftp resource

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save the csv file to a temporary file stream using [`ftp_fget()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php). This allows you to avoid the "create-read-delete" cycle. Once you close the file stream it's like it magically never existed :)

```
$ftp_handle = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$remote_path = "/path/to/file.csv";
$tmp_handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

if (ftp_fget($ftp_handle, $tmp_handle, $remote_path, FTP_ASCII)) {
  rewind($tmp_handle);
  while ($csv_row = fgetcsv($tmp_handle)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
fclose($tmp_handle);
```

If you wanted to loop over a directory of files just get the list of files and then put the above code in a loop.

Comment: that's cool. i didn't know it was possible to create temporary files without specifying file names

Comment: yeah that changed my life for a minute back when i first discovered it -- very helpful when you're working with text files from an ftp connection

Comment: yeah, i can think about a bunch of places in our application that we find the system temporary folder path, generate a random filename, save content to it, and of course forget to delete these temp files. this can solve anything for us. thanks again :-)

Comment: it's worth noting that you can also use "php://memory" in place of "php://temp" -- the difference being that 'memory' ONLY stores things in memory while 'temp' will store something in memory until it reaches a given size (the default is 2 MB), then transparently switch to the filesystem. read more here on the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: It seems the first parameter for ftp_fget is $ftp_stream (FTP connection resource).
bool ftp_fget ( resource $ftp_stream , resource $handle , string $remote_file , int $mode [, int $resumepos = 0 ] )

Comment: @AlexanderPalamarchuk Woops! Thanks for catching that. I definitely left out the first parameter. Corrected.